# Kendo-Scheduler clear selection

Tags: kendo-scheduler

How to clear the selected events on kendo scheduler. I have a button outside the scheduler clear selection and removes all selections. I need to clear the selections on kendo on click of this button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try passing `null` as parameter to the `select` method?

[select method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-select)

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/oyiKo - This approach works on my side as seen in this demo (it will set and then clear the selection after 2 seconds).

Comment: I am sorry, that is working. I had another code somewhere else which overrided that.

Comment: on my side, select(null) clear current selection but select the first slot of the view (week view in my case) : not the wanted behavior

Answer (score 1):

While this does clear the selection, it doesn't refresh the change event. Clicking on the last event selected will not fire the change event. You have to click on another event first.